# Integration of the permission_handler package on android 13 to access the phone storage

Tags: flutter, android-permissions

After integration of the package permission_handler to request permission to access the storage of the phone, the code works with android 9 and below but with android 13 it does not work at all, I'm really stuck:
Here is the code of my manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

Here is the code of the main:

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_notification');

const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
);

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) {});

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]).then((value) => runApp(const App()));

  await JustAudioBackground.init(
    androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.bg_demo.channel.audio',
    androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
    androidNotificationOngoing: true,
  );

  await AccountServices().initialization.then((value) {
    Get.put(CartController());
  });
}
```

Here is the error return after code execution:

```
E/flutter (  897): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (  897): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter (  897): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (  897): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:151:12)
E/flutter (  897): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (  897): #3      main (package:rmfitness/main.dart:34:3)
E/flutter (  897): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 13 not need to ask **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission. You have replace it with READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO based on your need.(**this is when your app targeting SDK 33**)

Ex:

1. Images and photos: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
2. Videos: READ_MEDIA_VIDEO Audio,
3. Audio files: READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

Refer this [android 13 behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13).

Now for your error you have to add notification runtime permission for android 13.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)